# why kruskal's algorithm and dijkstra's algorithm are so similar to each other?

Tags: algorithm

I know that these two algorithms are used to solve different problems, dijkstra's algorithm is used to find shortest path in a graph while kruskal's algorithm is used to find the MST of a graph.But they are so similar to each other? what's the relationship between them? and what's the relationship between these two authors? why they are so similar?

Comment: Err... Because the problems are very similar? I mean a MST basically consists of several shortest paths.

Comment: if so, why naming the algorithm with another name

Comment: I don't think either of them hang around on SO, and they'd be the only people to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @BitHigher if dijkstra had discovered both algorithms, they could each be called dijkstra's algorithm. (ps: just pulling your leg)

Comment: @BitHigher- Just both are greedy. there is no similarity between them... Kruskal finds MST of graph and Dijkstra find Shortest path.

Comment: @Shashank_Jain but the idea and process of these two algorithm are very similar

Comment: yeah because they greedily choose at each time ! oh common !

Comment: @Shashank_Jain he meant prim's not kruskal's. prim's is actually similar enough to dijkstra's that it could confuse somebody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different algorithms. In Kruskal you pick the shortest edge in the entire graph (and remove it from further consideration). In Dijkstra you pick the **vertex** with the shortest tentative distance (and remove it from further consideration).

Naturally, the problems solved are quite different too. The shortest path between two vertices may not be part of the minimum spanning tree.

An example is a square with sides 1, removing any one edge will give you a minimum spanning tree but the shortest path in the original square graph between the vertices of the edge you removed is not part of the minimum spanning tree.

---

From the comment:

Well, Prim's is closer to Dijkstra than Kruskaln. For completeness, Prim's always picks the closest vertex to the tree so far. In contrast, Dijkstra may not pick the closest vertex to the set of finalized vertices. For example, a hexagon with clockwise edge lengths 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4. Prim's could grow clockwise the whole time. Dijkstra would grow both ways.

Comment: you're lucky i'm bored ;)

Comment: I think you may confuse the kruskal's algorithm and prim's algorithm

Comment: well, prim's is closer to dijkstra than kruskal, which makes me wonder about your question. for completeness, prim's always picks the closest vertex to the tree so far. in contrast, dijkstra may not pick the closest vertex to the set of finalized vertices. for example, a hexagon with clockwise edge lengths 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4. prim's could grow clockwise the whole time. dijkstra would grow both  ways.

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry that I confused kruskal's and prim's

Comment: @BitHigher you are welcome. it was a good question -- prim's is indeed quite similar and i had to think a bit before i could find a reasonable example.